# Can i trigger a specific app share extension skipping the system dialog?

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

My issue is pretty straight forward. If a user in my app triggers a share flow from a link, is there a way i can **skip the share sheet (the UIActivityViewController) that iOS presents** and instead have that action always present the (this is only an example) **note app's share extension**?

**i.e. skip this**

[image: sharedialog]

**and go straight to this**
[image: notesShareExtension]

Comment: It depends on what app you want to open. For instance you can't open the notes app.

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter I don't want to open the actual app, just get access to it's share extension.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282225/how-can-i-open-my-app-directly-from-the-ios-share-sheet